# How to fix multiple error messages after executing a code through unittest class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, data-structures

I've created a code that iterates a dictionary over three different functions.

The main function is this:

````
> def main():
> # initial roster
>     brave_roster = {      "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",       "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15,
> AVG: 0.266",   } ```
> 
> The Three Functions are as follows: ``` def
> lookup_player(brave_roster, name):   name = input("Enter the name of
> the player you want to lookup:\n")
>      if name in brave_roster:
>     
>     print("Here are the", [name], "stats:", brave_roster[name])   else:
>     print("That player does not exist.")
> 
> def add_player_to_dict(brave_roster, name, stats):   name =
> input("Enter the name of the player you want to add:\n")
>      if name not in brave_roster:
>     stats = input("Please add Matt's stats:\n")
>     brave_roster[name] = stats
>     brave_roster.update([(name, stats)])
>     print("Here's", name,"'s stats:\n")
>     for name, stats in brave_roster.items():
>      print(name, ':', stats)   else:
>     print("That player is already on our roster.")
> 
> def delete_in_dict(brave_roster, name):   name = input("Enter the name
> of the player you want to remove:\n")   if name in brave_roster:
>     del brave_roster[name]   else:
>     print("\n uh typo?", name, "does not play for us")
> 
> if __name__ == '__main__':   print("\t ***  Braves Stats!  ***\n")  
> print("Welcome to My Braves Stats!")   brave_roster = {
>     "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",
>     "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266",   }
>      choice = input("Please type your choice number:") if (choice == "1"):
>     lookup_player(brave_roster) elif (choice == "2"):
>       add_player_to_dict(brave_roster) else: 
>     (choice == "3")
>     delete_in_dict(brave_roster)        print("\nThanks for using my Braves Stats.")
> 
> ```
> 
> Essentially from these three functions and the main code I'm supposed
> to use inputs to look up, update, or delete a roaster of players from
> a baseball team.
> 
> I have to make sure the earlier code runs in the test codes. However,
> I keep getting errors such as:
> 
> > **FAIL: test_add_player_duplicate (__main__.TestDictFunctions.test_add_player_duplicate)
> > ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last): line 106, in
> > test_add_player_duplicate
> >     self.assertEqual(actual, expected) AssertionError: {'Austin Riley': 'AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168,[80 chars]214'} != None**


What am I doing wrong?



Here is the test file:
````

> import unittest class TestDictFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
>
> def test_search_player_success(self):
> test_dict = {         "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"
> }
> actual = test_dict["Austin Riley"]
> expected = lookup_player(test_dict, "Austin Riley")
> self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
>
> def test_search_player_no_result(self):
> test_dict = {         "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"
> }
> actual = "N/A"
> expected = lookup_player(test_dict, "Ronald Acuna")
> self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
>
> def test_add_player_sucess(self):
> test_dict = {         "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"
> }
> actual = {        "Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273",       "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266"
> }
> expected = add_player_to_dict(test_dict, "Ronald Acuna", "AB: 467, R: 7 ``` 1, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266")
>
> ```
> self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
> ```
>
> def test_add_player_duplicate(self):
> test_dict = {"Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"}
> actual = {"Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273", "Austin Riley(2)": "AB: 350, R: 20, H: 120, HR: 5, AVG: 0.214"}
> expected = add_player_to_dict(test_dict, "Austin Riley", "AB: 350, R: 20, H: 120, HR: 5, AVG: 0.214")
> self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
>
> def test_delete_player_sucess(self):
> test_dict = {"Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"}
> expected = {}
> actual = delete_in_dict(test_dict, "Austin Riley")
> self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
>
> def test_delete_word_no_result(self):
> test_dict = {"Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273"}
> expected = test_dict
> actual = delete_in_dict(test_dict, "Shohei Ohtani")
> self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
>
> #uncomment to run tests unittest.main()

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]. Edit your question to make it legible.

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting is because the test code is passing three arguments to the add_player_to_dict function, but the function definition only accepts one argument (brave_roster).

To fix this error, you should modify the function definition to accept the additional arguments player_name and player_stats, like this:

```
def add_player_to_dict(brave_roster, player_name, player_stats):
  if player_name not in brave_roster:
    brave_roster[player_name] = player_stats
    print("Here's", player_name,"'s stats:\n")
    for name, stats in brave_roster.items():
      print(name, ':', stats)
  else:
    print("That player is already on our roster.")
```

Then, in the test code, you can modify the expected variable to include the new player name and stats:

```
expected = {"Austin Riley": "AB: 615, R: 90, H: 168, HR: 38, AVG: 0.273", "Ronald Acuna": "AB: 467, R: 71, H: 124, HR: 15, AVG: 0.266", "Austin Riley(2)": "AB: 350, R: 20, H: 120, HR: 5, AVG: 0.214"}
```

And when calling the function, pass the brave_roster, player_name, and player_stats arguments:

```
expected = add_player_to_dict(test_dict, "Austin Riley(2)", "AB: 350, R: 20, H: 120, HR: 5, AVG: 0.214")
```

With these changes, the test code should run without errors.

Also, note that in the delete_in_dict function, you should add a return brave_roster statement after deleting the player, so that the modified dictionary is returned to the calling code.